# How to run Scheduler in a SaaS based platform on their local timezone at everyday 12:00 am?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-schedule

My server is associated with one timezone. But I want to run the scheduler based on every country's local timezone daily at 12:00am. How can I do that?

Comment: Each server is capable of working in time zone independent way, i.e. in UTC. So calculate UTC of 12:00 in each time zone and run that many jobs? There around 40 time zones, shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Would you please explain or share me some resources to do that?

Answer (score 0):

- create a scheduler run once every 1 hour
- and your client setting will have 1 field timezone
- based your server timezone with you client setting timezone to run task for specific client
- tip: you can set your server timezone is 0 for easy caculate

Comment: There are more timezones than every hour, e.g. Iran is in UTC+03:30, Afghanistan is in UTC+04:30. Of course your solution might be ok, depending on the actual requirements.